# Различное поведение кода при вызове метода fork

Tags: c, процесс, ос

Имеется следующий код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
 
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("1) Proccess: pid:%d\n", (int) getpid());
    pid_t rc = fork();
    if(rc == 0){
        printf("child\n");
    }
    else if(rc > 0){
        printf("parent\n");
    }else{
        printf("error\n");
    }
    printf("2) Proccess: pid:%d\n", (int) getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции и запуске через терминал имеем следующий вывод:

```
Hello World!
1) Proccess: pid:97683
parent
2) Proccess: pid:97683
child
2) Proccess: pid:97684
```

При запуске в QT Creator вывод такой:

```
Hello World!
1) Proccess: pid:97674
parent
2) Proccess: pid:97674
Hello World!
1) Proccess: pid:97674
child
2) Proccess: pid:97675
```

То есть код до вызова метода `fork` вызывается дважды. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему возникает такое поведение в QT Creator и можно ли это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Популярная проблема, связанная с буферизацией вывода. Используйте `fflush` или небуферизирующий способ вывода, чтобы у другого процесса на момент старта был чистый буфер